Is $ACF_0 \models \phi \iff \phi \in ACF_0$ correct?
I was asked to prove the following:

Let $\cal L$ be a first-order language and $\Sigma$ be a theory in $\cal L$. Prove that $\Sigma$ is complete if and only if $\Sigma$ is maximally consistent.

This result to me looks wired, because if $\Sigma$ is maximally consistent then for all sentences $\phi$, we have that $\Sigma\models\phi\implies\phi\in\Sigma$, and take for example:
$$\Sigma = ACF_0 = \{\text{axioms of fields}\}\cup \{\text{axioms expressing algebraic closure}\} \cup \{\text{axioms stating that it has characteristic } 0\}$$
We know that $ACF_0$ is complete, so according to this result, $ACF_0$ would be maximally consistent meaning that $ACF_0 \models \phi \iff \phi\in ACF_0$.
Honestly, to me, this looks weird. I was not expecting that the only sentences that are semantic consequences of $ACF_0$ would be the axioms of $ACF_0$ itself.
So my question is: Is this correct, or am I missing something here?

Your confusion is understandable, and you do not seem to miss anything essential. My guess is that this is due to the definitions or conventions involved... Can you give the precise definitions you are working with? In particular, what does "complete" and "maximally consistent" mean for you? And what is the exact definition of a "theory" (e.g., a set of sentences, or maybe it has to be closed under consequence)?

A theory is just a set of sentences. A theory $\Sigma$ is maximally consistent if for any consistent theory $\Gamma$, $\Sigma \subseteq \Gamma \implies \Sigma = \Gamma$. A theory $\Sigma$ is complete if any two models are elementarily equivalent or equivalently if for any sentence $\phi$, either $\Sigma \models \phi$ or $\Sigma \models \neg \phi$ @MarkKamsma

With those definitions the thing you were asked to prove is simply not true. You already gave a counterexample. If theories were assumed to be closed under consequence (or maximally consistent would somehow mean "$\Sigma \subseteq \Gamma$ with $\Gamma$ consistent implies $\Sigma \models \Gamma$") then this would hold.

It's probably a typo on the exercise then. But is everything apart from that claim correct? Now I'm worried more things that I assumed were facts are also typos @MarkKamsma

But for example, here https://planetmath.org/maximallyconsistent I think they use the same definitions as I do, and they were able to prove this result @MarkKamsma

In the page you linked, the very first step in their proof is "$\Delta$ is deductively closed", so they use the definition that a theory is closed under consequence. It might be a bit annoying that there is more than one definition (convention maybe?) going around, but as far as I can tell you have correctly understood the concepts and ideas involved. By the way, I think the exercise you quoted is still a good exercise if you add the assumption "theories are closed under consequence".

Don't they prove that the way I defined maximally consistent implies that $\Delta$ is deductively closed? @MarkKamsma

I did not read properly indeed, but my point actually still stands. In their proof that complete consistent implies maximally consistent, they conclude by "then $A \in \Delta$ since $\Delta$ is deductively closed". So once again they use a definition were deductive closure (what I called "closed under consequence") is built in.
